# Sorting Query Azure Mobile services

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, azure

I have a Azure mobile service and I would like to sort the result before handing them to the receiving end.

This is the GetTables function :

```
 // GET tables/BPNews
    public IQueryable<BPNews> GetAllBPNews()
    {
        return Query().OrderByDescending(x => x.DateStart).Where(x => x.DateStart <= DateTime.Now && x.DateEnd >= DateTime.Now);
    }
```

I would like to have the results sorted by 'DateStart', but whatever property I sort by it's not been sorted at all.

Here is the BPNews class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;

namespace BeautyPointGroningenService.DataObjects
{
public class BPNews : EntityData
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
}
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

UPDATE (result) :

[{"id":"02A99F29-859A-4ED1-991F-D9BF1EDD6BDB","dateEnd":"2014-12-19T00:00:00Z","dateStart":"2014-12-12T00:00:00Z","message":"test \r\n\r\nfadfasdf asdf asdf\r\n\r\na\r\ndsf a\r\ns\r\nf\r\nas\r\n f\r\nasd\r\nf\r\nas\r\ndfasf\r\n a\r\nadf\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nfff\r\nf","date":"2014-12-13T13:02:43.14Z","subject":"test 23"},{"id":"5753D737-621B-4CD7-A80E-A20CF24CE013","dateEnd":"2014-12-30T00:00:00Z","dateStart":"2014-12-12T00:00:00Z","message":"bericht","date":"2014-12-19T12:53:21.91Z","subject":"test"},{"id":"620693A0-DE00-473E-9CB2-A9F69A1CC699","dateEnd":"2014-12-20T00:00:00Z","dateStart":"2014-12-13T00:00:00Z","message":"Dit is een nieuw bericht","date":"2014-12-13T12:52:00Z","subject":"Nieuw bericht"},{"id":"sample string 6","dateEnd":"2014-12-31T18:53:50Z","dateStart":"2014-12-11T18:53:50.487Z","message":"Dan hebben wij een leuke actie voor je! Met de kerst budget behandeling kun je voor een klein prijsje toch tip-top de feestdagen in. \r\n\r\nU kunt deze behandeling boeken bij Acties.","date":"2014-12-11T18:53:50.487Z","subject":"testKlein budget deze maand?"},{"id":"sample string 6ff","dateEnd":"2014-12-31T18:53:50Z","dateStart":"2014-12-11T18:53:50.487Z","message":"Tot 1 december kun je gebruik maken van deze knaller! \r\nStart voor 1 december met IPL van de onderbenen incl. knie en je betaald slechts €75 per behandeling! (normaal ongeveer €150) Heerlijk toch? \r\nVolgende zomer geen gedoe meer met scheren en waxen!","date":"2014-12-11T18:53:50.487Z","subject":"IPL onderbenen nu € 75 p.b"}]

Comment: Can you show any sample data?

Comment: OrderByDescending must be put after the Where expression.

Comment: Totally removed the where statement, but the sorting is still not done:

I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```
    // GET tables/BPNews
    public IQueryable<BPNews> GetAllBPNews()
    {
        return Query().Where(x => x.DateStart <= DateTime.Now && x.DateEnd >= DateTime.Now);
    }
```

...you can specify the sort order on the client by using OData query operations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj677199.aspx

So your query could look like:

```
    tables/BPNews?$orderby=DateStart
```

By using the Mobile Services SDK it is much more convenient:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#sorting

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

I ended up using : tables/BPNews?$orderby=DateStart&desc and got the result I wanted!! 
Thanks again!

Comment: uhmmm typo. I ment: BPNews?$orderby=DateStart%20desc
This works!